# Need to set subject of mail triggered from Log4Net in code C#

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, subject

I am trying to trigger error mail using **log4net**, after changes in config file, I am able to generate the mail from log4net. But I need to set the mail subject dynamically in C# or config based on environment and URL, any suggestions or idea ?

Guys, I need to know whether it is possible to set the mail subject of log4net mail in code behind .cs file, please comment on this ?

Comment: bool isDevelopment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Development";

Comment: How do I set the subject of the mail triggered ?

Comment: mail.subject = $"({isDevelopment ? "DEV" : "NOT DEV"})  some text {AnotherVariable}";